# How to use output of Azure Data Factory Web Activity in next copy activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a ADF Web activity from which I'm getting metadata as an output. I want to copy this metadata into Azure Postgres DB. How to use the Web activity output as an source to the next copy activity?

Comment: We can't  use the Web activity output as an source to the next copy activity.  I think you can use [Copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats) , use Generic HTTP or Generic REST as a source and use Azure Database for PostgreSQL as a sink.

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Kulkarni, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accoding to this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/129351/azure-data-factory-web-activity-save-output.html). I think we can use two Web activities to store
the output of your first Web activity.

Use `@activity('Web1').output.Response` expression at second web activity to save the output as a blob to the container. Then we can use Copy activity to copy this blob into  Azure Postgres DB.

[image]

Since I do not have permission to set role permissions, I did not test this. I think this solution is feasible.

Comment: Hi Joseph, here how we are copying data(output of Web activity as input to copy activity). you have shown 2 web activities. How we can use web activity output as copy activity input as copy activity needs a (input)dataset?

Comment: The first web activity is used to send web requests. The second web activity is used to save the response of the first web application to azure blob.

Comment: @JosephXu Can you please suggest how to handle this issue when blob public access is not permitted?

Comment: @JosephXu Do you have any idea how extract property from the web activity, when the property's name contain a special character (e.g. "Total-Count") ? 

At the moment I have something like: @activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders.Total-Count

Unfortunately, this expression does not compile...

Comment: @JosephXu, a) url path to be provided REST API or storage account path?
b) what is the purpose of x-ms-version: 2017-11-09 in Headers?